# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error while getting data from database

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, stored-procedures

I want to execute a `table` and get its data from the `database`. So I am calling a stored procedure like below:-

```
PROCEDURE GETSAPIDINFO
(
 P_SAPID IN NUMBER,
 OUTPUTTABLE OUT SYS_REFCURSOR 
)
AS 
BEGIN

OPEN OUTPUTTABLE FOR 

SELECT SAP_ID, STATE,LATITUDE, LONGITUDE FROM R4G_OSP.ENODEB
WHERE SAP_ID = P_SAPID;  


END GETSAPIDINFO;
```

and filling its data in a `datatable`

```
public DataTable ExecuteDataTable()
    {
        DataTable dt = null;
        try
        {
            if (this.OpenConnection())
            {
                this._oracleCommand.Connection = this._oracleConnection;
                this._oracleCommand.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("OUTPUTTABLE", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output));
                dt = new DataTable();
                OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(this._oracleCommand);
                da.Fill(dt);
                da.Dispose();

                this._htblOutParamenter = new Hashtable();
                foreach (OracleParameter op in this._oracleCommand.Parameters)
                {
                    if (op.Direction == ParameterDirection.InputOutput)
                        this._htblOutParamenter.Add(op.ParameterName, (object)op.Value.ToString());
                }

                this.CloseConnection();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            this.CloseConnection();
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

but I am getting error as

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error

at this line

`da.Fill(dt);`

I don't know why I am getting this error.

Comment: could you check SAP_ID  DataType

Comment: @SinghKailash: hey, its `NVARCHAR2(30)`

Comment: Oh Please modify as below approach :    WHERE SAP_ID = CAST (P_SAPID AS NVARCHAR2(30));

Comment: Or declare variable as:            P_SAPID IN NVARCHAR2(30),

Comment: @SinghKailash: yes done, thanks kailash.. now its working

Comment: Why do you declare `P_SAPID IN NUMBER` when `SAP_ID` datatype is `NVARCHAR2(30)`? You should declare `P_SAPID IN NVARCHAR2` or even better `P_SAPID IN R4G_OSP.ENODEB.SAP_ID%TYPE`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: actually, the table was designed by other guy.. so my eyes didnt went their. Now as per kailash, I changed the datatype in my procedure to `nvarchar2` and it worked properly

Comment: @SinghKailash: can you add the comment as an answer so that BNN can accept it. I just read the answer and all the comments to see that it was already solved...

Comment: Never do `throw ex;` where `ex` is a caught exception. Simply `throw;` if you want it to rethrow. Of course, that begs the question, why are you catching it in the first place if the only thing you're going to do is rethrow?

Comment: @ wolφi:   I have added answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please modify below changes:

WHERE SAP_ID = CAST (P_SAPID AS NVARCHAR2(30));

OR

Declare variable as: 
P_SAPID IN NVARCHAR2(30),

Comment: Thanks Kailash singh :)